# How do I configure Gnome Shell to use Super-# for shortcut keys?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get Unity-style Super+[1-9] keyboard shortcuts for launching apps in Gnome Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73030/can-i-get-unity-style-super1-9-keyboard-shortcuts-for-launching-apps-in-gnome)

I've just installed Gnome Shell instead of Unity, and so far I like it more. However, there's something from Unity that Gnome Shell is lacking, and that's the ability to launch the shortcuts from the dash using Super + n, where n = 1,2,3...

Is there a way of configuring it so it works the same way?

Comment: In short, no.  Gnome Shell doesn't work that way.  The favorites in shell aren't expected to be visible all the time like on Unity, so shortcuts of this kind would make less sense, but you could achieve something similar with a little work by setting up custom commands in Keyboard settings.  You can then bind launching of commands to keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to mark this question as a dupe, but it is a dupe of this question, which now has an answer posted:

[Can I get Unity-style Super+[1-9] keyboard shortcuts for launching apps in Gnome Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73030/can-i-get-unity-style-super1-9-keyboard-shortcuts-for-launching-apps-in-gnome/76626)

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/713/when-we-see-a-potential-duplicate-how-should-we-handle-it-when-we-dont-have-pr

Comment: Four years later, let me tell you that the question you've linked is the duplicate, not mine. Check the dates, mine was first.