# Gnome 'Super-#' hotkey like in Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher

I've been using unity for a while, and just switched to gnome. (Gnome 3.2 on Ubuntu 11.10)

I've liked it a lot, but it's missing one key feature (in my mind). In Unity you can use the super button with a number key to open an app on the launcher. For example: Chromium is my second app on the unity launcher, so I can press super-2 to launch it.

Is there any way to do this in Gnome? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition, I am looking for a link to the part of the Unity source code that provides this. We should make a Gnome extension that provides this functionality and port the Unity code over to Gnome 3. It is a great UX improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want the same thing, and... there's an alternative to that and works pretty well, explained by [Mark in his answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73030/can-i-get-unity-style-super1-9-keyboard-shortcuts-for-launching-apps-in-gnome/76626), using **xbindkeys** & **wmctrl**.

Just install them both packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Then create `.xbindkeysrc` in your home directory and put your desired programs like this:

```
"wmctrl -xa Nautilus || nautilus"
    Alt + 1

"wmctrl -xa Chrome || google-chrome"
    Alt + 2

"wmctrl -xa SublimeText2 || sublime-text-2"
    Alt + 3

"wmctrl -xa Filezilla || filezilla"
    Alt + 4

"wmctrl -xa Firefox || firefox"
    Alt + 5
```

Then log off your account and login back again.

Using ALT+# open an instance of the defined program on `.xbindkeysrc`, or if that app it's already running then the shortcut will focus on that app.
Sadly you have to manually put what programs you need on your `.xbindkeysrc` file, but it  works superb ;)