# key shortcut to show own terminal

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I have a terminal already open among a bunch of stuff open and I am looking for a key shortcut to get the terminal right away.
I am aware of the alt+tab combination but it's to painful to repeatedly tap tab until I reach the terminal icon.

so how can I add a key shortcut to just get the currently open terminal?

thank you for any enlightenment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press Super (the Windows key) and the number of the terminal's icon in the launcher to quickly open the terminal's window. For example, if it is the fifth icon, <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> will focus the terminal window if it exists or open a new one.

- [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts/)
- You can also create a custom shortcut. See [Gnome 'Super-#' hotkey like in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109579/gnome-super-hotkey-like-in-unity) for an example.

Comment: Good one!  I didn't know it also worked for switching windows...  (I knew it worked for opening).  Terminal just got locked back to the launcher!

Comment: great the xbindkeyx & wmctrl is working great, another question, why kind of application can I add in there beside firefox, terminal and usual stuff?

Comment: @kokito pretty much anything that has a consistent window name. The `-a` part filters using the window's titles, so if your application's title is unpredictable, it will be difficult.

Comment: is there a way to give a path instead of a window name?

Comment: I don't know, but I don't there is one.