# Is there a way to mimic Windows 7's WinKey+Number shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, command-line, cinnamon

One of the biggest things I miss from Windows 7 when I'm on Linux is the ability to push WinKey and a number to switch to the program in that place on the task bar. (e.g. You push WinKey+1, and it switches to the first program in the taskbar.) Is there a way to replicate that on Ubuntu 12.10 with Cinnamon? I tried to add custom shortcuts to do it, but I don't know any commands to switch to windows by their place in the taskbar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

In Unity Desktop Environment this option is there by default.
Just hold the Windows key (also called super) and the numbers for the shortcut will appear on each program's icon.

I don't think Cinnamon has this option.

Answer (score 1):

In Unity that's how it works. If I hold Super (WinKey) it shows me the number to hit for each app in the launcher bar.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if it was possible in Cinnamon though.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the reference to Cinnamon.

Answer (score 0):

This [list of Cinnamon shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/linux/Linux-Mint-Cinnamon-Edition_17.2.html) suggests you can't switch among windows with Super+1..9.

However, see the solutions for Gnome in this [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73030/can-i-get-unity-style-super1-9-keyboard-shortcuts-for-launching-apps-in-gnome). Maybe one of them works?