# Unity style number shortcuts which also minimize the focused application?

Tags: shortcut-keys, application-switcher, window-management

Is there a solution on Linux similar to the Windows 7 Win+number, or Unity's Super+number shortcuts, which will also minimize the application if it is currently active and focused?

In Windows 7, if the application is already launched, and currently active, the shortcut will minimize the window, which I find very useful for reducing clutter and focusing on my task.

I've found [a solution here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73030/can-i-get-unity-style-super1-9-keyboard-shortcuts-for-launching-apps-in-gnome/282933#282933) to emulate the Super+number shortcut keys with `xbindkeys` & `wmctrl`. If this is the only solution known, could you suggest with a brief example how one would add the minimize action? (I imagine it would require testing states and conditionals, I am completely new to Linux and these commands so I have no idea if it is even possible).

Comment: PS: I am aware according to other answers on this site that the absence of minimize function in the Unity launcher is intended. Hopefully there is a way to emulate this with an alternative dock or script?

Comment: You can always minimize the current window with `Ctrl+Alt+0`..

Comment: I know there's various shortcuts to minimze a window, but I find the Windows 7 behaviour to be more intuitive. I like to reduce the clutter on the desktop to better focus on my task, usually 2-3 windows max. In a typical sequence I would bring up a browser with an article in it with Win+1, read up a bit then I would hide it again with the exact same shortcut key. Likewise if I wanted to type something in Terminal occasionally, I would press Win+3, do a few things, then press the exact same key again to minimze.

Comment: Anyway.. I was hoping maybe an experienced Linux user could suggest what scripting engine or solution I could use to implement this? I'm guessing there's no app that currently does this (DockbarX emulates Unity's behaviour and won't minimize the apps), so a helpful answer would suggest some scripting engine I could use, or perhaps an example with AutoKey that would focus a given app, just something to get me started. I will post a complete script here if I find a way to make it. Thanks.